# contain image in 60%-height-div, while keeping aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to accomplish:
- create a pop-up div (fixed), centered in view
 
- this pop-up should be 60% height of the browser window
 
- the contents of the pop-up should be an image and a 'x' above the upper right corner of the image
- the height of the image should be maximal, considering it should be contained in the div together with the 'x'
- the aspect ratio of the image should be maintained

I tried the following code

```
<div class="pop-up">
  <p class="exit-button">x</p>
  <img class="image" src="safari.png" width="1200" height="630" alt="" title="" />
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
body {
  background: #333;
}
.pop-up {
  position: fixed; 
  height: 60%; 
  width: auto; 
  left:50%; 
  top:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%); 
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  background:yellow;
  object-fit: contain;
}    
.exit-button {
   text-align: right;
   margin: 0;
   font-size: 300%;    
}
.image {
  height: 100%; 
  width: auto;
  opacity:0.7;
}
```

This code is not solving the problem, the image is not contained in the (yellow) div, as can be seen in the following screen shot:

http://www.michielvisser.nl/tmp/screenshot.jpg

How to contain the image in the div with maximal height for the image in the div and maintain aspect ratio?

---

SOLUTION 1: Remove the height and width from .pop-up and change height:100% in .image to height:60vh. That works perfectly. Apparently the child (img) will not adjust to the parent (div), but the parent (div) will adjust  to the child (img). Sounds like real life.

SOLUTION 2: Essentially the problem arises when the window is resized (except in firefox). The solution can be to redraw the image after a resize, this solves the problem:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('img').hide();
  setTimeout(function(){ $('img').show(); }, 1);
});
```

Comment: What is the version of your safari? `object-fit` is supported from 7.1 http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit. Here is a playground -> https://jsfiddle.net/24denouk/

Comment: I just downloaded safari for windows, it is 5.1.7. I changed the title of the questions, it needs to be working for all major browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems are:

1. You have an inline width and height set on your image, which is overriding the CSS styles for width and height on that image
2. The margin from your X is pushing the image down since the X is wrapped in a `<p>` tag.
3. You don't need `object-fit` at all.

The simple way to solve #1 is to delete the inline width and height from the image tag and leave it to the stylesheet.

Number 2 can be solved by wrapping the X in a `div` instead of a `p`, or you can use a pseudo element for it. I have taken the latter approach in the snippet below.

To solve #3, just delete the style from the stylesheet. (Having this property set in Safari actually messed things up for me.)

This snippet is tested in Safari 10.1.1. Note how the placeholder image is quite large by default (1000x800), but it only displays as big as it can per the parent div.

**Edit:** Based on your comments, let's revise this further so that we dictate the size on the image, and just let the wrapper take up the size of the image.

So on our image, in order to get it to be 60% as tall as the screen, we can do:

```
img {
  height: 60vh;
  width: auto;
}
```

Then, in our parent, we won't specify a width or height at all, but we can do `display: flex` just to make sure it is big enough to fit its contents.

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}
.pop-up {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: yellow;
}
.exit {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 300%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  right: -40px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 50px;
}
.image {
  height: 60vh;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="pop-up">
  <a href="#" class="exit">X</a>
  <img class="image" src="http://placehold.it/1000x800" alt="" title="">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this, but the 'x' is not above the upper right corner of the image. First, it is on the image (it should be above, this could be fixed with positioning), but also when the window is resized in different sizes the image moves to the left, where the 'x' stays at the right, so the image and the 'x' drift apart. The image should maintain the same width as the div in order to position the 'x' correctly, and this is not happening when resizing in different window sizes.

Comment: I fixed the X in an edit just now; sorry about that. I am a little confused what you are trying to accomplish with the div. Is it supposed to just overlay the image with an opacity (can we just use a pseudo element on the image instead)? Is it always supposed to be exactly the same size as the image? Or does the image sit on the div, so the div has one aspect ratio and the image has another?

Comment: The opacity is just temporarily to show where the image is and where the div is. The purpose of the div is to make sure the 'x' is above the upper right corner of the image. This is only accomplished when the width of the div matches the width of the image. So: (1) how to get the image to fill the remaining height of the div (which is 60% height) and (2) how to make sure the width of the div matches the width of the image.

Comment: This what I get with your recent edit: [link](http://www.michielvisser.nl/tmp/screenshot2.jpg) . The width of the div and the width of the image do not match, therefore the x is far to the right of the image.

Comment: Can we assume that you know the aspect ratio of the image in the code, or is this supposed to work for any generic image of any size?

Comment: It's for an image gallery (photographer's website). So not all images will be the same. There's landscape and portrait photos for a start, and some have different aspect ratio than normal 2:3 photographs.

Comment: I see. Okay, take a look at the latest edit. I believe it should suit your needs.

Comment: As a quick note, one problem you may run into (which I am not sure how you're gonna avoid in any approach) is that with panoramic pictures, since your CSS is based on the image taking up a certain height and having an automatic width, you could get a situation where the image is too wide to fit on the screen and ends up getting cut off. To deal with that situation, you may ultimately decide it's better to do different classes on images of different proportions (e.g., landscape-ish, portrait-ish, panoramic) and set up a few different CSS styles for image width/height for those classes.

Comment: Ok, that shouldn't be a problem, no panoramic images here. The code works well, except: is there any way to make the 'x' a link this way? Javascript should be called when clicked upon the 'x', to close the image. This is different than clicking on the image, which is for showing the next image.

Comment: Yeah, I probably shoulda thought of that. In that case, using an actual `a` tag is probably best since we can't select pseudo elements with JavaScript. You can either omit the `href` and give it a tab index or give it an `href` and use `event.preventDefault()` in your JS. If for whatever reason it'd be easier to position things if you had child elements, you could use a `div` and nest the `a` inside that, but I didn't bother with that in the latest edit.

Comment: Ok, I’ll go for my code, but with a change (that’s from your code): remove the height and width from .pop-up and change height:100% in .image to height:60vh. That works perfectly. Apparently the child (img) will not adjust to the parent (div), but the parent (div) will adjust  to the child (img). Sounds like real life. Thanks.

Comment: Lol. Yeah, sorry for the going in circles a bit. Thought you wanted a different effect at first. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I put the image above the P tag and added some CSS to .exit-button and .image

From here you can adjust padding and sizing of the elements.

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}
.pop-up {
  position: fixed; 
  height: 60%; 
  width: auto; 
  left:50%; 
  top:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%); 
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  background:yellow;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.exit-button {
   position: absolute;
   text-align: right;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   margin: 0;
   font-size: 300%;    
}
.image { 
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  opacity:0.7;
}
```

```html
<div class="pop-up">
  <img class="image" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/johanchalibert/mac-osx-yosemite/1024/safari-icon.png" width="1200" height="630" alt="" title="" />
  <p class="exit-button">x</p>   
</div>
```

Comment: Thanx. Same as above. The 'x' is not above the upper right corner of the image. First, it is on the image (it should be above, this could be fixed with positioning), but also when the window is resized in different sizes the image moves to the left, where the 'x' stays at the right, so the image and the 'x' drift apart. The image should maintain the same width as the div in order to position the 'x' correctly, and this is not happening when resizing in different window sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and edited it. Please tell me whether this is the output you wanted or not.

```
body {
  background: #333;
}
.pop-up {
  position: fixed; 
  height: 60%; 
  width: auto; 
  left:50%; 
  top:50%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%); 
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  background:yellow;
  object-fit: contain;
}    
.exit-button {
  margin-top: -50px;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 0;
  font-size: 300%;    
}
.image {
  margin-top: -20px;
  height: 100%; 
  width: auto;
  opacity:0.7;
}
<div class="pop-up">
  <p class="exit-button">x</p>
  <img class="image" src="safari.png" alt="" title="" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I get in chrome, or any other browser than firefox: http://www.michielvisser.nl/tmp/screenshot-chrome.jpg
The image is not contained in the div and the width of the image and the div are not the same. Therefore, the x is not above the upper right corner of the image...

Answer (score 0):

Because of either needing to hardcode in the alignment of the image given the size or deal with weird convolution, I believe this is the best way:

Create a fixed overlay occupying the entirety of the screen, create a container of 60% height, align it in the center with flexbox and stick the image inside making it occupy the entire height. The aspect ratio will update automatically (only happens with `height`).

As for the button – give it absolute positioning and a right position of 0, and manually give the parent relative positioning (this is necessary).

```
<div id="popup">
  <div id="container">
    <a href="">X</a>
    <img src="https://i.redd.it/gelilvo30mgz.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

#popup {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#container {
  position: relative; !important // has to be specified for the children (anchor) to find the bound
  height: 60%;
  background: #333;
}

a {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L2nLjjxc/1/

I believe that's the least amount of convolution if you want it to be dynamic.

Comment: sorry, does not work. The 'x' is not in the right spot and the height of the container is not working, I can fill in anything for the height of the container but it does not change the output.

Comment: Hey, sorry. Totally forgot about this. Yeah, wasn't working at all before.